PyQt6 and PySide6 app, process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
I'm building a simple financial desktop app which contains several QMainWindows (each is defined in its own class). One of those is importing another file in which a GraphChart is defined.
At first, the graph was working on its own but couldn't be added as a widget to one of the main windows:
Figurecanvasqtagg can not be added as a qwidget between classes
Added "from PySide6 import QtCore" before "import matplotlib" as said here:
FigureCanvasQTAgg can't be added as a QWidget
Problem solved.
Last week, bought new computer, reinstalled PyCharm, placed the project file under "PycharmProjects".
Tried to create a new venv folder and choose the previous interpreter (i.g. from the original project folder) but:

Getting "Non-zero exit code (103)

So I've created a new interpreter:

But than, when I choose in the app menu the main window that creates the GraphChart externally, the app crashes with the exit code mentioned.
The structure of the QMainWindow class that creates the GraphCart externally, is similar to the QMainWindow thats creates the chart in its own file, regarding the centralwidget and layout, and it did work before I moved PC. Sorry for not providing the full code, its pretty long but I don't think its related, seems to me I'm missing some basics setups and configurations when opening the folder as a new project.

You don't have to provide the full code, but providing absolutely no code at all makes it almost impossible to help you. You must provide a [mre], and please carefully read and understand what that link explains. That said, PySide and PyQt are conceptually similar, but can not be used together, so if that's what you're doing, you have to choose one or the other.
